# Question about the composition of a 1902 non-polarisable electrode diagram by Jagadis Bose

Tags: electrochemistry, chemical-biology, electricity

In his work, "[Response in The Living and Non-living](https://archive.org/details/responseinliving1902bose)" (1902); page 6, Jagadis Bose describes a method for detecting nerve response. He explains that he uses iso-electric contacts with no current in the galvanometer and diagrams a non-polarisable electrode. The following are his diagrams:
[image: diagram]

On Diagram C, one will note that he uses a strip of saltwater soaked cloth attaching to a node that contains, what appears to be, a Zinc Sulfate solution with a Zinc rod resting in this ZnSO<sub>4</sub> solution.

Below the ZnSO<sub>4</sub>, there's a seemingly unspecified area that acts as an intermediary between the ZnSO<sub>4</sub> and the "strip of cloth."  I have highlighted it in yellow in the diagram below.

***Could someone please explain what this medium may be or what could be used in it's place?***  It appears to be some kind of solid or interstitial porous material (or another compound that he does not mention). Or is it simply a generic attachment or some kind of neutral absorbent material (perhaps sand?) that acts as a medium between the Zinc Sulfate, the "node" and the moistened cloth?

Here is Diagram C enlarged and highlighted for viewing convenience:
[image: highlighted cell]